# Split data from table to java process

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table **Students** which has **1.000.000** records.

I need to feed data 1.000.000 into Solr.

Because the number of record is very big, so I need to do it in parallel => I am going to create **5 processes**, each will process 20.000 records.

My problem is :

1. How to divide 1.000.000 into 5 parts that will be **the same all the time** (I considered ntile function, but I don't know whether data will change for-each select or not)

Comment: Can you explain what the sentence is about: `2. If can, I want to control more at case 5 process running, record have insert, update or delete to table`, I do not understand this sentence at all.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot parallelize retrieving process in Java. You can do it in database side. Oracle DB supports it for example.

Comment: @krokodilko I have remove problem 2.If can, I want to control more at case 5 process running, record have insert, update or delete to table. because it is unnecessary at time

Comment: @user3076539 Why not multi-threading?

Comment: @user3076539 I made multi-threading for each process. Now I want to  multi-process

Comment: @user3076539 Another option is to do the parallel processing at the database side with the use of stored procedures and invoke the stored procedure from Java.

Answer (score 0):

This question is in a sense related to **Batch Processing Design Patterns** (also: Large Scale Batch Processing). 
There is a concept called "Partitioning" there, which consists in dividing the input data into smaller pieces to be able to process them in parallel.
There are several partitioning strategies, You can read more about them here: [Spring-Batch processing strategies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.0.x/batch-processing-strategies.html), in a nutshell they are:

1. Fixed and Even Break-Up of Record Set
2. Breakup by a Key Column
3. Assigned to a batch instance via a partitioning table
4. Assigned to a batch instance by a portion of the value (e.g. values 0000-0999, 1000 - 1999, etc.)
5. Breakup by Views
6. Addition of a Processing Indicator
7. Extract Table to a Flat File
8. Use of a Hashing Column

It's hard to say which one would be the best in your case, one would need to know more details.

Answer (score 0):

NTILE() that's what I've used in these situations.